# AzureBlobStorageOnIoTEdge: Error Target container connection not specified, upload turned off

Tags: docker, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-edge

My local blob storage is not uploading blobs to my cloud storage account. It reports back

```
        "configurationValidation": {
            "deviceAutoDeleteProperties": {
                "deleteOn": {
                    "Status": "Success"
                },
                "deleteAfterMinutes": {
                    "Status": "Warning",
                    "Message": "Auto Delete after minutes value not specified, auto deletion turned off."
                },
                "retainWhileUploading": {
                    "Status": "Success"
                }
            },
            "deviceToCloudUploadProperties": {
                "uploadOn": {
                    "Status": "Success"
                },
                "cloudStorageAccountName": {
                    "Status": "Error",
                    "Message": "Target container connection not specified, upload turned off."
                },
                "cloudStorageAccountKey": {
                    "Status": "Error",
                    "Message": "Target container connection not specified, upload turned off."
                },
                "uploadOrder": {
                    "Status": "Success"
                },
                "deleteAfterUpload": {
                    "Status": "Success"
                }
            }
        },
```

I am pretty sure that it should work. My desired properties are

```
            "deviceToCloudUploadProperties": {
                "uploadOn": true,
                "uploadOrder": "OldestFirst",
                "cloudStorageConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*****;AccountKey=******;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
                "storageContainersForUpload": {
                    "***": {
                        "target": "***"
                    }
                },
                "deleteAfterUpload": true
            }
```

The container exists locally and on the cloud site. I copied the primary connection string from my local storage account into the configuration. The local storage is working, I can see that my container was created and contains data but it doesn't want to synchronize with the cloud. Why is it saying "Target container connection not specified, upload turned off."? It sounds like this part is missing

```
                "storageContainersForUpload": {
                    "***": {
                        "target": "***"
                    }
                },
```

but obviously it is not.

I'm using the latest docker image of this service. Is there any chance to use an older version? Some months ago I could make it work already. I tried to use a different version like mcr.microsoft.com/azure-blob-storage:1.4.0 but it doesn't accept any other tags than latest.

Thx!

Comment: You mentioned that your desired properties in your Device Twin are showing configuration correctly. Though the device needs to announce the configuration in Reported Properties as well. Just wanted to be sure it is configured both on desired and reported Device Twin? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#device-twins

Comment: I guess I somehow know what happened here. I chose to create a general deployment for a number of devices instead of a custom deployment. There you need to specify the module twin property where the default value is proposed as "properties.desired.settings". I fear I used that default value which in fact put my desired properties into a subtree of the original desired properties and so the module didn't find it. When defining a custom deployment for a single device, there is no such option and thus you cannot make that mistake there. I'll investigate further and answer myself if thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between my working version of the local blob storage module and my non working version was that the non working version was deployed by a deployment plan. In the deployment plan you cannot just paste the module twin settings of the documentation of the blob storage on IoT edge like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-deploy-blob?view=iotedge-2020-11

You need to split the configuration into two parts where the first part looks like this
[image]

and the second part looks like that
[image]

And that totally makes sense. If you want to update your modules you probably want to keep your configuration because there might have been some changes which were made e.g. by a customer. This gives you the possibilty to add some properties to your inital configuration later without changing anything what was already configured. In fact every device can keep its individual configuration at any time.

My wrongly configured reported proterties were hidden in the suggested default path "properties.desired.settings" and thus the edge runtime could not find it.