# How to configure target container for Azure blob Storage in docker-compose?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Blob Storage in my docker with **docker-compose.yml**:

```
...
  azureblobstorage:
    container_name: azureblobstorage
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azure-blob-storage:latest'
    ports:
      - "11002:11002"
    environment:
      - LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=account
      - LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=key
    volumes:
      - azureblobstorage:/blobroot
      - ./var/containerdata:/srv/containerdata
    networks:
        - network
...
```

When I run `docker-compose up`. It says:

`[error   ] [tid 1] Microsoft.Azure.Devices.BlobStorage.Common.TieringConfiguration: Target container connection not specified, upload turned off.`
On stackoverflow, I found this article:
[AzureBlobStorageOnIoTEdge: Error Target container connection not specified, upload turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68128916/azureblobstorageoniotedge-error-target-container-connection-not-specified-uplo).
According to it, there should be some configuration template, but I don't understand how to apply it to docker container.

Answer (score 0):

There are environment variables mirroring the values in the IoT Edge module configuration template. You can configure these in `docker-compose.yml` in order to test the blob storage module locally.

The environment variables are:

- `deviceToCloudUploadProperties__uploadOn` - accepts `true` or `false`
- `deviceToCloudUploadProperties__uploadOrder` - accepts `NewestFirst` or `OldestFirst`
- `deviceToCloudUploadProperties__cloudStorageConnectionString`
- `deviceToCloudUploadProperties__storageContainersForUpload__<sourceName>__target` - refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob?view=iotedge-1.4#devicetoclouduploadproperties)
- `deviceToCloudUploadProperties__deleteAfterUpload` - accepts `true` or `false`

Microsoft Documentation: [deviceToCloudUploadProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-store-data-blob?view=iotedge-1.4#devicetoclouduploadproperties)